# Sorting a list of multiple Class objects a by value

Tags: python-3.x

So I have spent an embarrassingly long time on this but am really getting nowhere fast.

I need to sort a list of multiple class values obtained from a one key in a dictionary.
The list would look like this, with a variable number of list elements.

```
[<__main__.OrderRecord object at 0x02D357D0>, <__main__.OrderRecord object at 0x02D35850>]
```

The elements in each class object are included in this:

```
class OrderRecord:
    """The OrderRecord class
    Data attributes: date of type str
                     location of type str
                     name of type str
                     colour of type str
                     ordernum of type int
                     cost of type int
"""
def __init__(self, file_line):
    """Takes a given file line and initialises an OrderRecord instance"""

    split_file = file_line.split(",")
    self.date = split_file[0]
    self.location = split_file[1]
    self.name = split_file[2]
    self.colour = split_file[3]
    self.ordernum = split_file[4]
    self.costs = self.cost_of_order()
```

So I'm trying to get that list of class objects to be sorted in place by ascending "ordernum" e.g low numbers first. It is the 4th index in the class object. Hopefully I have included all the relevant information here.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that you have your list of `OrderRecord` elements called `the_list`.

You can sort it in-place using:

```
the_list.sort(key=lambda e : int(e.ordernum))
```

you have to convert the sort key to integer if you use the class as-is, or you have to do that in the constructor:

```
self.ordernum = int(split_file[4])
```

In which case you can directly sort like this:

```
the_list.sort(key=lambda e : e.ordernum)
```

not converting to integer could lead to false assumption that it works but it would sort *alphabetically* and thus `125` would be before `13`, which is not what you want.

Note: if 2 objects share the same `ordernum` and you want to add a second criterion (or more...), less prioritary you can do like this (return a tuple as the sort key, using `attrgetter` which creates the tuple for you):

```
the_list.sort(key=lambda e : e.attrgetter(ordernum,name))
```

(now assuming that `e.ordernum` is already an integer type)

Comment: The last one would probably be nicer with `operator.attrgetter()`.

Comment: @alecxe you mean `the_list.sort(key=lambda e : e.attrgetter('ordernum'))` ? what is the benefit of this (honest question, no irony intended)? never mind, I'm getting it now, editing. You can do it only if `ordernum` is already an integer, but yes that's really cleaner (and it fixed my typo at the same time :)